# Duplicate Handle to Read file

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a file which is exclusively opened by a Process A (a third party application). I obviously couldn't open the file in my application, so I thought of Duplicating the Handle using DuplicateHandle API.

However, I realized that the change in position of the file handle will also be reflected in Process A as well , which could cause undesired behaviour. Is there a way I can duplicate the file handle for reading, without affecting the file Handle (position) in Process A?

Comment: The fundamental problem you're trying to bypass is non-exclusively opening a file which is exclusively opened. There's generally a reason files are exclusively opened.

Comment: *"I obviously couldn't open the file in my application"* - I don't see, how that is obvious. You can open as many handles to a file as you want, as long as they agree on compatible access and sharing modes. You never even explained, what access and sharing mode process A uses, and you never explained, which ones you need.

Comment: @IInspectable the OP clearly states that process A has the file open for exclusive access. That means no sharing mode is used, so noone else can open the file regardless of access rights requested.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: A statement like that is all too often a misinterpretation (confusing requested access with sharing mode). So far the OP hasn't responded and provided the missing information. Besides, not setting a sharing mode doesn't prevent opening a file handle (e.g. with `SYNCHRONIZE` access rights).

Comment: Process A is a third party application (not developed by me), which does not allow me to programmatically read nor manually copy\paste the file in concern. I was hoping if I could do it may be using some IO Driver API or something.But I guess there is no way I can read an exclusively (no share read\write access) opened file. Thanks for your help. Apologies if I was not very clear in my question. –

Comment: @JudeAloysius: You still haven't provided any information on how the file is opened by the third party application (use a tool like [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find out). Nor have you shown the code you used to open that file. It wouldn't be the first time someone was puzzled about an `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` only to find out, that they provided the wrong sharing mode rather then the wrong desired access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out:

1. First, you need to create a Duplicate file handle using [NtQuerySystemInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724509(v=vs.85).aspx) and [DuplicateHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251(v=vs.85).aspx) API.
2. Using the duplicate handle now [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) handle and followed by [MapViewOfFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) . MapViewOfFile maps certain portion of the file to the your process address space and can be used to read the file without disturbing the current file offset of the of the original file handle.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Can you provide some code, please?

Answer (score 2):

No way. A `HANDLE` to a file is really an indirect pointer to a [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx), and if the file is open in synchronous mode (`FileObject->Flags & FO_SYNCHRONOUS_IO`) then `FILE_OBJECT.CurrentByteOffset` is used as the file pointer offset. You share the same `FILE_OBJECT` when you duplicate the handle. In order to have an independent file pointer, you need to open another independent `FILE_OBJECT`/`HANDLE` to the file.